# How to extract date from timestamp with timezone

Tags: postgresql

I want to extract a date in format `yyyy-mm-dd` (`'2010-12-31'`) from a timestamp with timezone (`'2010-12-31 00:00:00+02'`) and use it to compare with another date in format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I want to use something like `date_part('day',mydate)` but to be able to extract the year and month too.

Comment: Cast it to a `date`, e.g.: `the_timestamp_column::date`

Comment: It's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Cast it to a date, e.g.: `the_timestamp_column::date`